# Make Foreach after meeting a condition in List

Tags: c#

I am creating a static sign in page using List to save the data. I am using a ForEach to loop through the list but the issue I am facing is I want my for loop to stop immediately the condition is true.

NB: I have tried using a break and a return but they are not working as expected.

The code is here:

```
List<User> users = new List<User>(3);
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        User superAdmin = new User()
        {
            userType = "Super Admin",
            uniqueCode = "123456",
            password = "password1"
        };
        User admin = new User()
        {
            userType = "Admin",
            uniqueCode = "654321",
            password = "password16"
        };
        User userOperator = new User()
        {
            userType = "Operator",
            uniqueCode = "109105",
            password = "specialpassword"
        };

        users.Add(superAdmin);  
        users.Add(admin);
        users.Add(userOperator);
    }



    private void login_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string userType = cmbAdminType.Text;
        string uniqueCode = txtUniqueCode.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;

        foreach (User userPick in users)
        {        
            if (userPick.userType == userType && userPick.uniqueCode == uniqueCode)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cool you are in!");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Err, not found!");
                break;
            }

        }

    }
}
    public class User
    {
        public string userType { get; set; }
        public string uniqueCode { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

Please, what else can I do?

Comment: What's wrong with `break`? If you're looking for alternatives you can also `return` a value to break out.

Comment: are you sure that the if condition is correct? you may test its value

Comment: @Adriani6 break will work for the first value and return false for all others

Comment: @david Yes, the if condition works well for the first test.

Comment: @heywhydot16 Ah, I see what you did now. I completely missed the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Others have pointed out the flaw in your current code, but I'd suggest using a LINQ approach here. It's much shorter and easier to read - at least when you're used to LINQ:

```
bool validUser = users.Any(user => user.userType == userType && user.uniqueCode == uniqueCode);
MessageBox.Show(validUser ? "Cool you are in!" : "Err, not found!");
```

`Any` is short-circuiting: it stops as soon as it finds a match.

As a side-note, I'd strongly encourage you to start following .NET naming conventions for your properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your recommendation is noted!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this could be because you have a logical error in the way that your code is working.

Currently, you break from your `foreach` loop on the first successful match, or the first unsucessful match.  So basically, your enumeration will break after 1 iteration whether successful or not.

You could introduce a flag that you use to record success, or not, and then test this after the enumeration, as so:

```
private void login_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string userType = cmbAdminType.Text;
    string uniqueCode = txtUniqueCode.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;
    bool isMatched = false;

    foreach (User userPick in users)
    {        
        if (userPick.userType == userType && userPick.uniqueCode == uniqueCode)
        {
            isMatched = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isMatched)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cool you are in!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Err, not found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped too.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop stops after the first object found in the list. I think what you want to accomplish is that it breaks either when the object you looked for is found either at the end of the loop, if the object you were looking for had not been found. The code:

```
bool userInside = false;
foreach (User userPick in users)
    {        
        if (userPick.userType == userType && userPick.uniqueCode == uniqueCode)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cool you are in!");
            userInside=true;
            break;
        }                
    }
if (userInside==false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Err, not found!");
    }
```

I hope this helps. ^^